# Optimize simple image carousel in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I am creating a simple carousel in my Angular 8 app. All it has is a next and previous button where one can slide the images left and right. Since I don't want to use any external libraries lie `jQuery` and `NgB` I startes coding with pure `JS`. As you can see from my code sample its quite a tedious process, so I was thinking there must be an Angular way to optimise this so I have come to ask for your input and suggestions.

Below is my html where the first slide gets the class `activeSlide` and the others get `inactiveSlide`. The `inactiveSlide` is set to `display: none; transform: translateX(-100%); ....` and the `activeSlide` has corresponding CSS that makes the slide visible.

```html
  <div class="tours-right">
    <div class="tours-arrow-left" (click)="getNextSlide()">
    </div>
    <div *ngFor="let image of pdfCovers; let i = index;" [ngClass]="i == 0 ? 'activeSlide' : 'inactiveSlide'" class="tour-container">
      <a href="{{image.link}}" target="_blank">
        <div class="tour-img" [style.backgroundImage]="'url(' + image.img + ')'">
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="tours-arrow-right" (click)="getPrevSlide()">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Below is my `.ts` with my two functions `getNextSlide()` and `getPreviousSlide` and the JS is quite tedious.

```js
  getNextSlide() {
      //figure out the Angular way
    let slideWrapper = document.querySelector('.activeSlide');
    slideWrapper.classList.remove('activeSlide');
    slideWrapper.classList.add('inactiveSlide');
    let nextSlide = slideWrapper.nextSibling;
    nextSlide.classList.add('activeSlide');
    console.log(nextSlide);
  }

  getPrevSlide() {
    //figure out the Angular way
  }
```

Essentially I would like to create something like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-carousel-component) but simpler yet still how one would do it the Angular 8 way! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try a structural directive. carousel is actually a typical example for structural directives. Have a look here for example:

https://netbasal.com/understanding-angular-structural-directives-659acd0f67e